# Text file not opening in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to open a txt file using C++, and it doesn't open.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    vector<string> lines;
    
    ifstream myfile("AAAA.txt");
    

    string contents;

    
    cout << "START" << endl;
    
    if(myfile.is_open()){
        myfile >> contents;
        cout << contents << "AAAAAAAA" << endl;
    }
    
    
    
    cout << "END";
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

The code in the if statement isn't running, which I assume means the file isn't opening. How can I get the file to open?

My .cpp file and my .txt file are in the same folder, and I'm on Windows 11. I'm using Visual Studio Code, and my tasks.json looks like this:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-static-libgcc",
                "-static-libstdc++",
                "-static",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: It looks like your IDE is doing some shenanigans and moving things to different folders. Either play its game and put resource files in whatever folder it tells you to, or just compile from the command line.

Comment: Try using a full and absolute path for the file. Or make sure your run configuration (in the `launch.json` file, which you don't show us) have the correct [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) set up.

Comment: Windows provides an API (`GetModuleFilename`) to return the full path of your application.  Use that to derive the directory it resides in and put your files in there.

Comment: The tasks json is for the build command. The cwd there isn't related to program-runtime; it's related to toolchain runtime. You want to configure a launch.json, setting the cwd there to wherever your data files are located.

Comment: *My .cpp file and my .txt file are in the same folder* That's irrelevant, suppose you coped your program to another computer, would you expect it to be trying to open a file on the original computer? What really matters is what the *current working directory* is. In this scenario that will be set by VSCode based on the configuration files you have. In particular look at the `cwd` setting in `launch.json`.

Comment: _"it doesn't open"_ - So, what is the reason for it not opening? Did you try `ifstream myfile("AAAA.txt"); if(!myfile) std::perror("AAAA.txt");` to see what it says?

Comment: Relying on the current working directory being anything in particular is a no-no.  Find another way.

Comment: Changing the cwd in my launch.json to ${fileDirname} worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code in DevC++ with a sample text file of my own, and it did display its contents. Try checking if you not have sufficient rights to access the folder where the file is saved. Sometimes, if you save in C drive, you might not be able to access certain contents. Try saving the program and text file in a different location and run the code.

Or try giving out the absolute path of the file.

Besides, do check if you run the program from the current working directory.